# How to send multipart/form-data file?

Tags: angular

I have this in html:

Choose File

```
  handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("myFile", files.item[0]);
    this.api.postWithoutEntity('/socialintegration/callback/attachment', { recipientId: this.selected.custSocId, file: formData }).subscribe();
    this.upload = false;
  }
```

but im getting this: Current request is not a multipart request"

Any suggestion?

Comment: You are not using headers variable

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your this.api.postWithoutEntity method works, but you aren't using headers variable. 
You must pass your headers on request

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });

return this.http.post<any>(
  "/socialintegration/callback/attachment",
  {recipientId: this.selected.custSocId, file: formData},
   headers
);
```

https://angular.io/guide/http#updating-headers

Comment: what is this post<any> it say that cannot be any beccause is not expecting paramaters

Comment: when you use <> specify the type of data you expect the server to respond to, with <any> you say anything, however you could put <User> or some object you have modeled

Comment: It is useful because you have the help of the editor with the names of the properties and their methods when handling the subscribe response